# git force pull with implicit rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have two machines, `1` and `2`. Machine `1` is used for the development of code, while `2` is a remote server used for tests and high-performance calculations.

My git repository has two branches, `master` and `remote-test`.
The following graph shows the current state of the git repository on *all* machines:

```
A --- B --- C             master
             \
              `-- D       remote-test
```

Machine `1` always uses the `master`-branch, while my remote server (machine `2`) always resides on the `remote-test`-branch.

When developing new code, I add new commits to the `master`-branch on machine `1`:

```
A --- B --- C -------- E      master
             \
              `-- D           remote-test
```

I then re-base `remote-tests` onto commit `E` and force-push the new branch:

```
A --- B --- C -------- E           master
             \          \
              \          `-- D'    remote-test
               \
                `-- D              remote-test (on machine 2 only)
```

When I connect to my remote server via SSH, I want to pull `remote-test` without having the need to handle any merge conflicts etc.

**Is there a possibility to use a "force-pull" on machine `2` to override the local copy of the `remote-test`-branch?**

*(I guess, I could always do `git fetch; git checkout origin/remote-test`, which puts the head in a detached mode ...)*

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think that I found the answer:

```
git fetch; git reset --hard origin/remote-test
```